# How can I feed Audiocontext with pcm Data using Web Audio Api

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have a function **startPlayer()** which create a player with audiocontext and a function **feed(data)** which is called when I received a new audio chunk.

audio chunk: [sample rate: 48000], [bytelength: 4096], [channel number: 1]

I'm using a **bufferSourceNode** in order to play the chunk audio. But i'm only using one but the **buffer** seems to be settable only once because I got the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to set the 'buffer' property on 'AudioBufferSourceNode': Cannot set buffer to non-null after it has been already been set to a non-null buffer
    at feed (http://127.0.0.1:5500/audio.js:112:21)
```

Maybe I should create a **bufferSourceNode** and connect it to **audiocontext.destination** every time **feed(data)** is called, but it seem too much.

Here my code:

```js
async function startPlayer() {
  playerAudioContext = new AudioContext();
  sourceNode = playerAudioContext.createBufferSource();
  sourceNode.connect(playerAudioContext.destination)
}

async function feed(pcmData) {
  const data = new DataView(pcmData)
  audioBuffer = playerAudioContext.createBuffer(1, data.byteLength / 2, playerAudioContext.sampleRate);
  const channelData = audioBuffer.getChannelData(0);
  for (let i = 0; i < data.byteLength; i += 2) {
    const sample = data.getInt16(i, true);
    channelData[i / 2] = sample / 32768;
  }


  // Set the buffer on the source node and start playing
  startTime = currentTime;
  const bufferDuration = audioBuffer.duration;
  sourceNode.buffer = audioBuffer;
  sourceNode.start(startTime);
  currentTime += bufferDuration;
}
```

Yes maybe there is better solution for parsing the data into the **channelData** but I don't think that's a problem here.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `AudioBufferSourceNode` for each new chunk of audio.

But as you mentioned in your comment below it's not very efficient to do this that frequently. You can also create an `AudioWorkletProcessor` which receives the audio data from the main thread and plays it just in time.

It's possible to send the data with regular `postMessage()` calls. But doing it with a `SharedArrayBuffer` instead would be even more efficient.

Comment: yes, this is the easiest solution I found, I was wondering if there wasn't a more... efficient way. Because it looks like a lot to recreate a bufferSourceNode 25 times every second

Comment: Sorry, I've overlooked that your buffers are very short. I've edited my answer.